# Connect Android App to local MySQL DB using my Java library

Tags: java, android, mysql, jsp, connection

I need help: I developed a web app in java, creating a library of functions that call to interact with the database from jsp. At the moment I'm developing android application that does the same thing as the web app. My goal is to connect the mysql database that I created earlier, possibly using the code from my java library (db connection, all the editing functions of the database), to the android application.

I have read several tutorials discussing remote connections using php, but I'm looking for better solutions that allow me to use the code that I have (with all queries) using my database locally.

What is the best solution to use? Can you help me in choosing and maybe recommend me some good tutorials?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to (for example) add a servlet or web-service to your web-application that will interact with your previously created function library, and your android app can send requests over network to those servlets/services.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the problem correctly, but I simply use the JDBC Driver. Works like a charm!

Edit: Here's the tutorial I used: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=bO7O9tS8qe4

Comment: Web application is finished, connected to the database and it working fine. My problem is to connect the same database locally on my android app.